# When I set up SSL/TLS in React and Spring using CloudFlare, no axios requests are made from React to Spring

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, ssl, cloudflare

It's a bit long, but I've listed all the situations to make it specific to the situation I'm in, and I hope you understand...

I installed react and spring on a Linux Ubuntu server and separated the frontend from the backend. I'm using axios to communicate with react when I need to make specific requests.

I also installed and used Nginx to deploy the react application. When I enter the ip address from an external PC, it enters normally.

I purchased a domain called isakgo.com from CloudFlare and registered it with DNS Records. Now, when I type in isakgo.com and enter it, I get to the webpage fine.

The problem occurred while setting up HTTPS. In CloudFlare, I set Full (strict) in SSL/TLS, enabled Always Use Https, and generated an 'Origin Certificate' and 'Private Key' via Create Certificate in CloudFlare.

I moved these keys into the /etc/ssl folder on Linux. I named the Origin Certificate isakgo.com.pem and the Private Key isakgo.com.key.

Next, I set the sites-available/default file in Nginx to the following.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name isakgo.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name isakgo.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/isakgo.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/isakgo.com.key;

    location / {
        root /root/front_react/my-app/build/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Restart Nginx and go to isakgo.com, and you will automatically be directed to https://isakgo.com.

Now that we're on https when accessing our react application, it's time to set spring to https. I proceeded as follows

Using the isakgo.com.pem and isakgo.com.key that we created in CloudFlare earlier, I created a keystore in pkcs12 format because spring doesn't recognize the pem format. I executed the following command to create it.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey isakgo.com.key -in isakgo.com.pem -out keystore.p12 -name jspSpring
```

Now I moved the file named keystore.p12 inside src/main/resources, which is the path corresponding to classpath: in spring. Then I opened application.yml with vim and modified it like this

```yaml
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-store-password: my-password
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-alias: jspSpring
```

That's it, we have built the spring project with ./gradlew build command and executed that spring project with java -jar command (using built-in Tomcat).

Now, press a specific button on the react server (isakgo.com) to send an axios.post request to spring with the following format.

```js
await axios.post("https://isakgo.com/api/processLogin");
```

/api/precessLogin is the endpoint that is associated with the @PostMapping annotation in spring.

However, we get the following error here.

```
xhr.js:251 POST https://My-IP:8443/api/processLoginnet::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

It says it's invalid, but I'm not sure where I made a mistake - I'm guessing it's the openssl part, but that's not quite right.

Also, to try another way around it, I tried using Let's Encrypt instead of using the .pem and .key issued by CloudFlare. With that, after modifying the Nginx config file appropriately, I get the following error when I run it.

```
POST https://My-IP:8443/api/processLogin net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

My guess is that the above issue is caused by using CloudFlare and using Certbot at the same time. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this issue, while still utilizing CloudFlare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issue with your configuration and PKCS12 file. Also, I have verified your service URL (https://isakgo.com:8443/api/processLogin) which seems ok. Can you please confirm whether you can access the URL in the same browser, and it shows secure in your browser.

Comment: I found the cause of issue. it was because I was missing port 8443 when sending request from axios in react to spring.